# MongoDb query to retrieve top 10 scores

Tags: mongodb

I have the data on my mongodb like this,

```
[{
    name: "user1",
    image: "image",
    score: 10
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    image: "image",
    score: 167
  },
  {
    name: "user3",
    image: "image",
    score: 1
  },
  {
    name: "user4",
    image: "image",
    score: 102
  },
  {
    name: "user5",
    image: "image",
    score: 12
  }
]
```

I would like to retrieve the top 10 scores in descending order. Can someone help me out with the query for the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you like to handle score ties?

Comment: I haven't thought about that still. Can I add a timestamp to it and use it as a tie breaker?

Comment: Of course, you can sort by multiple fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PaQueLGeAMh)

explained:
You can do with find() or aggregate() using the two stages sort + limit

Option 1 - find:

```
 db.collection.find({}).sort({score:-1}).limit(10)
```

Option 2 - aggregate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
     $sort: {
       score: -1
     }
   },
   {
     $limit: 10
   }
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sort()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#mongodb-method-cursor.sort) and [limit()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#mongodb-method-cursor.limit) methods from `MongoDB` but notice that:

> If using limit() with sort(), be sure to include at least one field in
> your sort that contains unique values, before passing results to
> limit().

```
 db.collections.find().sort( { score: -1 } ).limit(10)
```